# Selenium Python XPATH Can i print the value of an html tag id attribute to the console

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have an HTML with a div tag which has an ID attribute.  The ID value is dynamic.
I have managed to build an XPATH to locate the ID attribute and get's it's value into a variable.
Can i print out the value to the console?  I want to know what value the variable has got.

I tried to print the value  the following but i get errors:
I tried:

```
print id.text
print id.get_attribute("id")
```

The errors are:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The Selenium Python code is:

```
element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[starts-with(@id,"operations_add_process_list_task")]//span//button')
    id = element.get_attribute("id")
    print id.text
```

The XPATH is:

```
(By.XPATH, '//*[starts-with(@id,"operations_add_process_list_task")]//span//button')
```

The HTML is:

```
<div id="operations_add_process_list_task_2">
    <span/>
<span>
<span class="myinlineblock" title="Clean"
      style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;">
<select tabindex="-1">
</span>
</span>
<span>
<span class="" title="Turn group off or on." style="">
<input type="checkbox" checked="" tabindex="-1"/>
</span>
</span>
<span>
<button class="gwt-Button" title="Add the tasks to the selected group." style="display:block;" type="button">Add tasks
</button>
</span>
</div>
```

Once I know what the value is I can then use the ID for the next locator e.g.

```
select = Select(WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="%s"]/span[2]//select' % id))))
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: How about `print id` ?

Comment: The `button` object that you point to doesn't have an `Id` attribute... Do you want to get `Id` of `div` element `"operations_add_process_list_task_2"` ?

Comment: And yes, as har07 specified, `get_attribute()` method returns a `str`, so there is no need in `id.text`

Comment: Yes I would like to find the element which has operations_add_process_list_task_2.  But there is another element above with operations_add_process_list_task_1  This is why I went down to the button so i can get the right element.  If i use operations_add_process_list_task it highlights 2 elements.  If i add the button it highlights the 2nd element which is what i want.

Comment: I would like to get the ID value of the element which has the button

Comment: I tried print id, it prints blank

Comment: I have used the debugger and I can the variable id is empty. It is trying to get an ID value of a button.  Button does not have an ID attribute.

Comment: Can i locate the button and then locate it's parent div tag which has the ID attribute.  I can then get the ID value out?

Comment: I am going to try this //button[text()="Add tasks"]/ancestor::div[1] This highlights the div tag with the ID above the button

Comment: Yes this has printed out the ID, this XPath works. //button[text()="Add tasks"]/ancestor::div[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can change the XPath to be as shown below to return the element with `id` that also contains the `button` element :

```
//*[starts-with(@id,"operations_add_process_list_task")][.//span//button]
```

Or you might want to use `child` axes instead of `//` if the span is direct child of the element with the target `id`, because the former will be *slightly* more efficient :

```
//*[starts-with(@id,"operations_add_process_list_task")][span/button]
```

Comment: Cool, Thanks for your help